# Where can good VS Coded UI references be found?

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

Coming from Winrunner, Quick Test Professional and Selenium, it suprised me that there is not much to find on the internet about VS Coded UI testing except for the standard MSDN resources.

Is it true there are not much good references, blogs or fora about this subject or do I use google the wrong way?

Some of my found resources:

- [Blog of RBurnham](http://rburnham.wordpress.com/category/coded-ui-tests/)
- [MSDN Visual Studio UI Automation Testing forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsautotest/threads)
- [Nice try but only two old entries blog](http://codedui101.blogspot.nl/)
- [Gautam Goenka Blog (MSDN again)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gautamg/archive/tags/coded+ui+test/)
- [Visual Studio Team Test Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/tags/coded+ui+test/)

Others found those:

- [Test Automation Using Visual Studio 2010 Coded UI Or MSDNs Absolute Essential Starters Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh875174.aspx) ([KMoraz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851112/where-can-good-vs-coded-ui-references-be-found/10851226#10851226))
  Mentional links in this article:
  [Anutthara Bharadwaj Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anutthara/archive/tags/coded+ui/)
  [Balachander G. Subramaniam](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/balagans/archive/tags/codeduitest/)
  [Singhal Rubels Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rubel/)
  [VSTS Quality Tools Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/)
- [Content Index for Coded UI Test on Mathew Aniyan's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2010/02/11/content-index-for-coded-ui-test.aspx) ([KMoraz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851112/where-can-good-vs-coded-ui-references-be-found/10851226#10851226))
- [Experiences from an Intern](http://blogs.windward.net/marcusj/2012/05/31/starting-out-with-coded-ui-tests/) ([Vi3GameHkr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851112/where-can-good-vs-coded-ui-references-be-found/10852925#10852925))

Comment: Also: Ed Blankenship's [Automated Load and UI Testing for SharePoint](http://vimeo.com/34629976)(video)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the patience, the MSDN documentation actually covers quite a bit.  The links provided by KMoraz are pretty helpful, once you sort through the vast quantity of links on those two pages.

Again, if you have the patience, I wrote a blog post highlighting a few of the articles (all of them listed on one of those two pages KMoraz provided) that helped me when I started out with Coded UI tests:

http://blogs.windward.net/marcusj/2012/05/31/starting-out-with-coded-ui-tests/

Comment: That is a bit the point, information is all scattered in the MSDN documentation. Take for example `Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel` mentioned in one of the links in your blog: How could we know that this exists and what it does without stumbling upon it in a MSDN entry? Compared to other testtools, VS Coded UI is very rich and has so many possibilities, but learning those possibilities seems hard.

Comment: You have a good point, even the API documentation is scattered more so than I would like.  This is where the saying comes in, "Sometimes you gotta jump in without your floaties" or something to that effect.  You are likely to be much more productive with Coded UI tests if you just start testing, and when you run into problems, search the MSDN documentation and forums for a solution, or ask here at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Diving in the deep... scary! Unfortunately the SO community for coded UI tests is not that big (only around 36 people are following the coded-ui-testing tag at this moment), while it is probably one of the largest on the internet. To get some attention you have to tag it also as C# (with a bazillion followers). Conclusion: Coded-UI-Testing users... Team up!

Answer (score 1):

[Content Index for Coded UI Test](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2010/02/11/content-index-for-coded-ui-test.aspx) has everything you need.

[Test Automation Using Visual Studio 2010 Coded UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh875174.aspx) - this is a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks! Bookmarked them.